Script not work for create machines by hyper-v
Hello my script not work for create machines by hyper-v
$list = Get-Content -Path "my place"

foreach ($vmy in $list) 
{
    New-VM -Name $vmName -MemoryStartupBytes (Invoke-Expression $memorySize) -Path $vmPath -Generation $generation
    Set-VMProcessor $vmName -Count $numberCPU
    Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -SwitchName $switchName
    New-VHD -Path "$vmPath\$vmName\$vmName.vhdx" -SizeBytes (Invoke-Expression $diskSize) -Dynamic
    Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $vmName -Path "$vmPath\$vmName\$vmName.vhdx"
    Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName $vmName -Path $isoFile

    Start-VM -Name $vmName
}

my txt is here
$vmName = "win2019main_"
$vmPath = "C:\Hyper-V\VMssTESTfinal_ab"
$memorySize = "4096MB"
$diskSize = '100GB'
$numberCPU = '4'
$generation = '1'
$SwitchName = 'Default Switch'
$isoFile = "C:iso"
$vmName = "win2019a"
$vmPath = "C:\Hyper-V\VMssTESTfinalbc"
$memorySize = "4096MB"
$diskSize = '100GB'
$numberCPU = '4'
$generation = '1'
$SwitchName = 'Default Switch'
$isoFile = "C:iso"
$vmName = "win2019bcd"
$vmPath = "C:\Hyper-V\VMssTESTfinalxz"
$memorySize = "4096MB"
$diskSize = '100GB'
$numberCPU = '4'
$generation = '1'
$SwitchName = 'Default Switch'
$isoFile = "C:\.iso"

what should I do?
My error is cannot bind argument to paramter 'command' bbecause it is null and more
I would like Create machine after script for one os work nice,
thanks in advance

It is possible to install also OS on script? Not with manuall create?

Please format your post properly.

What is the content of the file "my place"? The Get-Content command does not set any variable values. Have you investigated the ConvertFrom-StringData command? The $vmy variable is never used.

I add "my place" for example is Get-Content -Path "C:\Hyper-V\template.txt" and, template txt.txt have $vmName = "win2019main_"
$vmPath = "C:\Hyper-V\VMssTESTfinal_ab"
...till $isoFile = "C:.iso" and without investigate ConvertFrom-StringData - and yes now I see vmy variable is never used. What should I add for foreach ?

perhaps like this?
$vmName = "win2019main_", "win2019a", "win2019bcd"
$vmPath = "C:\Hyper-V\VMssTESTfinal"
$a      = "_ab", "bc", "xz"
$vmPath = $a | foreach {$vmPath + $_}
$memorySize = 4096MB
$diskSize   = 100GB
$numberCPU  = 4
$generation = 1
$SwitchName = 'Default Switch'
$isoFile    = "C\:iso"

$n = 0
foreach ($vmy in $vmName) {
    $Path = $vmPath[$n] + $vmy + ".vhdx"
    New-VM -Name $vmy -MemoryStartupBytes $memorySize -Path $vmPath[$n] -Generation $generation 
    Set-VMProcessor $vmy -Count $numberCPU
    Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmy -SwitchName $switchName 
    New-VHD -Path $Path -SizeBytes $diskSize -Dynamic 
    Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $vmy -Path $Path 
    Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName $Path -Path $isoFile
    Start-VM -Name $vmy
    $n++
}



Cool! THank you :)  I don't understand what does it mean " $vmPath = $a | foreach {$vmPath + $_}? and  $n = 0
foreach ($vmy in $vmName) {
$Path = $vmPath[$n] + $vmy + ".vhdx" ?
